# show an image in a method with logic

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to show a image after a specific logic, like if(x==1) { showImage }.
My problem is, that it won't display the webcontent until the image is loaded. The image should show up, like "pop in" .

My code until now:

```
class TestScreen extends Component {

componentDidMount() {

function images() {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = require("./design/icons/veh_symbol.svg");
        document.getElementById('imageDiv').appendChild(img).className = "logoEV";
    }
```

and here my "logic":

```
function testFunc() {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            sleep(1000)
            if (i == 5) {
                images();
            }
        }
    }
```

sleep() is only a workaround to test the delayed show up of the image.

My render method:

```
render() {

    return (

        <div className="TestScreen">
            <div id="imageDiv"></div>
        </div>

    );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you do not fully understand how react works yet.

With React, you can forget about `document.createElement` and `appendChild`, React does it for you, in its render function.

To achieve your goal, you should set a state in your component containing the future link to your image. Then set a timeout (do not use sleep) that will change your image in the state value.

Using `setState` will tell React to rerender your component on the screen, at this point, this image will be shown.

Working example :

```js
class TestScreen extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
   myImage: ''
  }

  setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ myImage: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/React-icon.svg' })}, 3000)
 }

 render() {
  const { myImage } = this.state

  return (
   <div className="TestScreen">
    {myImage ? <img id="imageDiv" src={myImage} /> : <p>No image :(</p>}
    
   </div>
  );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestScreen/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'/>
```

The render function will check if the image has been set in the state, if it exists, it will show it in an image tag, if not, it will show a paragraph containing a message. This is called conditional rendering.

Comment: one more question: I want to write a method, not the setTimeOut(), another like a simple if(x==1) { showImage}, where and how do I put the method?

Comment: It depends, does this method affects what will be rendered ? Can you tell me what it does

Comment: yes, the image should bei rendered, like with the setTimeOut() in the constructor. This works perfectly fine and I want the same exact same result of showing the image, but with my logic instead of "after 3 sec"-show-image. I hope you understand what I mean :-)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to render the image after `x` seconds ? Since your `testFunction` could be reduced to `sleep(5000)` Or are you trying to execute something every second until the image is shown ?

Comment: no, i don't want to render the image after a specific time, sorry, that was only an example to demonstrate my problem. The sleep() was only to test, if the image pops up after the given time, don't worry about it. I want to render the image after something happens, like ´if(someValue == true) { renderTheImage }`

Comment: Then simply add this callback inside the function you're using : `this.setState({ myImage: mySource})`. Inside your `if` for example